# Classic ASP as CGI - How to wrap asp.dll as an exe?

Tags: dll, vb6, asp-classic, cgi, webserver

I imagine it's possible to wrap asp.dll inside an .exe so that Active Server Pages functionality can be run on any web server (e.g. mongoose) which does CGI.

Has anyone done this before? Ideally, a compiled asp.exe would answer my question :-)

Runner up would be information on how to make a cgi-compliant exe because I reckon I can handle wrapping the asp.dll. Basically all you have is a request on stdin and a response on stdout tright?

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

Somehow I get the feeling this would be a huge licensing violation for asp.

Never mind the obvious question of Why Bother?  (Rhetorical)

Considering you get IIS for free on a MS machine, it would be assinine (IMHO) for a developer to try and get asp running outside of IIS.  There's no benefit and a huge potential of failure.

Next, I'm willing to bet a huge sum that asp.dll is not portable to a non-ms server... eliminating the concept of running classic asp on say a linux box...  Which mongoose is generally used for.

Consider this a gentle suggestion to preserve your sanity and legal butt: Abandon this whole idea.

Comment: It's more one of those Can We Do It? projects, setting the Should We? aside for a moment. I wonder: can any .exe work as a CGI extension? If so, I could wrap asp.dll as an exe which just takes stdin, processes and writes to stdout. Is that the interface?